# se nos casó Maria vs se casó nuestra Maria

Tags: pronombres

Is there any difference *in meaning* between the following sentences?

- Se nos casó Maria.
- Se casó nuestra Maria.

My understanding is that the pronoun "nos" indicates possession and there isn't any difference between both sentences. If that's indeed true, which sentence is more usual?

Comment: As for what is more usual I would say that at least in Colombia the first is the most common. The second could be used by Maria's parents but even them would usually use the first version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Between:

> a) Se nos casó María.

and

> b) Se casó nuestra María.

I can see at least three differences:

1. In (a) "nos" may indicate possession or interest. Maybe María is our friend, our sister, our daughter, and we are thus emotionally affected by her marriage. This emotional involvement is not necesssarily present in (b).
2. "nuestra María" may be used to indicate that there is more than one María, and it is ours (the one we know, the one who is related to us) that got married. As the possibility of there being more than one María is more limited, so is this use.
3. Both sentences are rather colloquial, but (b) is more so because it can be associated with the very colloquial use of articles before proper nouns: *Se casó nuestra María* could thus be equated to *Se nos casó **la** María*.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than focusing on the grammar, I'll focus on the practical meaning, and the feelings behind these sentences.

- Se nos casó Maria.

We might feel somewhat abandoned.  Comparable: *She up and got married on us*.

- Se casó nuestra Maria.

This focuses on our affectionate feelings toward her.  Comparable: *Our dear Maria got married, Darling Maria got married,* or *Our Maria got married.*  In UK English I've heard "our" used this way.

They express slightly different feelings and attitudes about the event.

I guess "Se casó nuestra María" might be less common -- perhaps it's a tiny bit awkward sounding.

Comment: What does "She up" mean ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista - It's an idiom.  Write back if you have trouble finding it and I will hunt for a definition.  I'm not good at making up definitions.  Have you heard sentences like this?  *He up and died.*